# MySQL Procedure error in server

Tags: mysql

I am getting this following error , the same code is not throwing any  error in my local system.

MySQL said:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '**GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN atv.alid = 1906962 and atv.atrtid = 1
>   THEN concat(replac**' at line 1

below i posted my code

```html
BEGIN
SET
  @@group_concat_max_len = 1024 * 13;
SET
  @sql3 = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
      'replace(format(SUM(CASE WHEN atv.alid = ',
      b.alid,
      ' and atv.atrtid = 1 THEN concat((atv.amount) , "") when atv.alid =',
      b.alid,
      ' and atv.atrtid = 2 then concat((atv.amount) , "") END),2), ", " , "") as ',
    REPLACE
      (
        CONCAT('`',
        TRIM(acl.name),
        '`'),
        '.',
        't'
      ),
      ' , replace(format( SUM(case when atv.alid = ',
      b.alid,
      '  and atv.atrtid = 2 then concat((atv.amount/',
      b.value,
      '*100),"") WHEN atv.alid = ',
      b.alid,
      ' and atv.atrtid = 1 then concat((atv.amount/',
      b.value,
      '*100) , "") end),2), ", ","") as ',
    REPLACE
      (
        CONCAT('`',
        TRIM(acl.name),
        '-value`'),
        '.',
        't'
      )
    )
  )
INTO
  @sql1
FROM
  business_tax_profile b
LEFT JOIN
  account_ledger acl ON(
    acl.alid = b.alid AND acl.company_id = 19
  )
WHERE
  b.butaptid = 2 AND b.butapsid = 1 AND b.company_id = 19;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
      'replace(format(SUM(CASE WHEN atv.alid = ',
      b.alid,
      ' and atv.atrtid = 1 THEN concat((atv.amount) , "") when atv.alid =',
      b.alid,
      ' and atv.atrtid = 2 then concat((atv.amount) , "") END) , 2) , ", " , "") as ',
    REPLACE
      (
        CONCAT('`',
        TRIM(acl.name),
        '`'),
        '.',
        't'
      ),
      ' ,  replace(format(SUM(case when atv.alid = ',
      b.alid,
      '  and atv.atrtid = 2 then concat((atv.amount/',
      b.value,
      '*100),"") WHEN atv.alid = ',
      b.alid,
      ' and atv.atrtid = 1 then concat((atv.amount/',
      b.value,
      '*100) , "") end),2) , ", " , "") as ',
    REPLACE
      (
        CONCAT('`',
        TRIM(acl.name),
        '-value`'),
        '.',
        't'
      )
    )
  )
INTO
  @sql4
FROM
  business_tax_sub_profile b
LEFT JOIN
  account_ledger acl ON(
    acl.alid = b.alid AND acl.company_id = 19
  )
WHERE
  b.butasuptid = 2 AND b.company_id = 19 AND b.butasupsid = 1;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
      'GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN atv.alid = ',
      c.alid,
      ' and atv.atrtid = 1  THEN concat(replace(format(atv.amount,2),", ","") , "") when atv.alid=',
      c.alid,
      ' AND atv.atrtid = 2 then concat(replace(format(atv.amount , 2),", ","") , "") END) as `',
      TRIM(ao.name),
      '`'
    )
  )
INTO
  @sql2
FROM
  extra_charges c
LEFT JOIN
  account_ledger ao ON(
    ao.alid = c.alid AND ao.company_id = 19
  )
WHERE
  c.ectid = 2 AND c.company_id = 19 AND c.ecsid = 1;
SET
  @sql3 = CONCAT(
    'CREATE OR REPLACE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED DEFINER = root@localhost SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `purchase_invoice_tax_report_view_19` AS SELECT i.pinvid as pinvid, ROUND(i.total_tax_amount,2) AS `total_tax_amount1`, i.outlet_chkid,i.receive_date as receive_date, i.total_qty, replace(format(i.payable_amount,2),", ","") as payable_amount, replace(format((i.complete_amount -i.total_tax_amount),2) , ", " , "") as total_amount_before_tax, v.gstin,   v.data as vendor_data,  group_concat((case when atv.alid = 35 and atv.atrtid = 1  then concat(replace(format(atv.amount,2),", ","") , "") when atv.alid = 35 and atv.atrtid = 2 then concat(replace(format(atv.amount,2),", ",""), "") end) separator " ") as `round`,',
    COALESCE(@sql1,
    '"0"'),
    ',',
    COALESCE(@sql4,
    '"0"'),
    ',',
    COALESCE(@sql2,
    '"0"'),
    ',  al.name as vendor_name , i.date, (CASE WHEN i.is_transportation IS NULL and is_expense = 0 THEN "Purchase" WHEN i.is_transportation IS NULL and is_expense > 0 THEN "Expense" WHEN i.is_transportation > 0 and is_expense >0 THEN "Transportation" ELSE "Purchase" END) as purchase_type,i.invoice_number ,(case when a.avtid = 3 then "Purchases" end) as voucher_type , a.avtid, i.pinvsid FROM purchase_invoice i   LEFT JOIN account_transaction atv ON(atv.avid = i.avid and atv.company_id = 19) left join account_voucher a on (a.avid = atv.avid and a.company_id=19) LEFT join vendor v on (v.venid = i.venid and v.company_id = 19) LEFT join account_ledger al on(al.alid = v.alid and al.company_id = 19) where a.avsid = 1 and a.avtid = 3 and a.company_id = 19 group by i.pinvid'
  );
PREPARE
  stmt
FROM
  @sql3;
EXECUTE
  stmt;
DEALLOCATE
PREPARE
  stmt;
END
```

is there any syntax error or anything else because the same code working fine in the local system ....

Comment: why don't you post generated query string for `@sql3`. it seems problem is that generated query string.

Comment: sorry @RavinderReddy I am not getting exactly what you trying to explain me .

Comment: The exception string which you posted is part of generated string from `@sql2` variable. and the error was raised when you used it to generate final sql string `@sql3`. before `prepare stmt from @sql3` try to debug the value of `@sql3` by calling `select @sql3`. Add printed sql string to your question.

Comment: select  @sql3 is returning NULL

Comment: that statement should be within your SP. it should be after `set @sql3 = ...` and before `prepare stmt from @sql3` statements. then execute the SP , preferably at `MySQL CLI` for testing purpose.

Comment: Please check the second code , I have done like this but its showing some other error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172141/discussion-between-sradha-and-ravinder-reddy).